# dial_action cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, using, android-intent

I have tried to execute a sample Intent application, but I am getting these errors in the java file:

> DIAL_ACTION cannot be resolved or is not a field
>   NEW_TASK_LAUNCH cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here's my code:

```
package android_programmers_guide.AndroidTeleDial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;


public class AndroidTeleDial extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent DialIntent=new Intent(Intent.DIAL_ACTION,Uri.parse("tel:5551212"));
        DialIntent.setLaunchFlags(Intent.NEW_TASK_LAUNCH);
        startActivity(DialIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's [Intent.ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL).

To avoid this kind of errors, if you're using eclipse, use the auto-completion feature: while typing a word, press ctrl+space and it will open a list of possible completions.

This way, trying to auto complete `Intent.DIAL` you would find that there's no such member in `Intent` class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `setLaunchFlags()` is used any more.  I think you just need to set the flag:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

And as @bigstones states, you should also use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: phone dialer example]

Try this code.

```
package android_programmers_guide.AndroidPhoneDialer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AndroidPhoneDialer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:5551212"));
        DialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(DialIntent);
    }
}
```